# Jquery receiving return value from $.post as array

Tags: jquery, json

I've read many threads about this and still not getting this to work, but got really close.
I'm sending data from jquery to my database, then my database will return a record: `$row['parcel_id]` and `$row['address]`, just 2 columns, which then is encoded to json using `json_encode()`.

In my query return `data`. I have something like this:

```
var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(data);
```

this returns:

```
{"parcel_id":"1","address":"5000 Charlotte Ave"}
```

However I can't do

```
data.parcel_id   or   data['parcel_id'].
```

So my question is what is that return value? is it an array? object?
How can I access each element?

Comment: Try doing `arr.parcel_id`, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks you very much for quick reply, I forgot to change it back to arr. I was doing var arr = JSON.parse(data); then data.parcel_id didn't work then I delete that line and forgot change it back.

Comment: er...arr.parcel_id.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're storing the parsed JSON in `arr`, you'll have to do:

```
arr.parcel_id
```

or

```
arr['parcel_id']
```